# Python Regex - Get Substring Starting with part of word and ending with certain character

Tags: python, regex

I've searched the forum high and low and just can't seem to piece together the knowledge to build a python regex for this. I need to get the date (Tuesday, May 12) out of this string. The actual date will vary, but will always include a day of the week (ex: Tuesday).

`["Text content goes here!","week","Yes","Tuesday, May 12",2,"110519",2]`

Answer (score 0):

a = ["Text content goes here!","week","Yes","Tuesday, May 12",2,"110519",2]
b = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
for text in a:
    for day in b:
        if type(day) == type(text):
            if day in text:
                print(text)

Try this.

Comment: Oh man, I'm confused I was expecting a very different looking answer.